# href property is wrong for a stylesheet object referenced by an @import in IE9

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-9, stylesheet, href

```
<head>
    <link href="Styles/StyleSheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

Using javascript I can get get hold of the above stylesheet1 object and retrieve the href which returns an absolute path which looks something like this:

> C:\Users...\myWebsite\Styles\StyleSheet1.css

StyleSheet1.css contains an @import:

```
@import url("StyleSheet2.css");
```

This is not qualified with the 'Styles' folder because StyleSheet2.css is in the same folder as StyleSheet1.css which is 'Styles'. It works as expected and imports the styles into the html document. However if I get hold of the stylesheet object that the @import references, it returns this for the href property:

> C:\Users...\myWebsite\StyleSheet2.css

Notice it is missing the 'Styles' folder.

Is this a known bug and is there a quick way around it?

Answer (score 0):

Html documents loads "Styles/StyleSheet1.css" from the location specified. And the import statement runs under the context of html document. Because of that browser will interpret the `@import url("StyleSheet2.css");` statement under DocumentsURL\StyleSheet2.css.

You may try with actual location
@import url("Styles/StyleSheet2.css");

Comment: The jscript engine is interpreting it as rooted at the document url but the IE engine is not. If I change the location to @import url("Styles/StyleSheet2.css"), the styles will no longer be picked up because IE will be looking for Styles/Styles/StyleSheet2.css.

Comment: In that case you my use `@import url("/Styles/StyleSheet2.css");` absolute URL scheme and IE will also interpret correctly. Just a / at the beginning.